# Toggle media-query on media-screen OR localStorage variable

Tags: css, media-queries, local-storage

I have one stylesheet, which has both mobile-layout definitions and desktop-layout definitions. I would prefer to still have just one stylesheet.

The stylesheet splits definitions into `@media screen and (max-width: 1049px)` and `@media screen and (min-width: 1050px)` to separate mobile and desktop layouts. Sometimes they share the same layout for certain elements, hence why I don't use two stylesheets.

I would like a footer button that lets the user manually switch between these, so even if their screen is under 1049px they can still opt to use the desktop layout. I'd like to store this choice in the `localStorage`.

The issue is, how can I tell the different media queries in the CSS to also check the `localStorage` variable, preferably without having two stylesheets? What are my options?